# ¿Como puedo darle solución al error Array is empty?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Estoy intentando crear un formulario de reserva y he seguido un tutorial hasta ahora, pero aunque lo he realizado tal y como se muestra en dicho tutorial por alguna razón me da especificamente este error:

`Exception: Array is empty: values`

```
        function actualizarPreguntas() {
    
      //Conectar con Sheets
      const libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const hoja = libro.getSheetByName("DisponibilidadFechas")
    
      //Traer opciones de Fecha
      const arregloFechas = hoja.getRange(2, 1, ultimaFila(1, hoja) -1,2).getDisplayValues();
    
      const opcionesFecha = arregloFechas.filter(fila=>fila[1]=="LIBRE").map(fila => fila[0])
    
      const formulario = FormApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com")
    
      //Actualizar Fecha
      **const preguntaFecha = formulario.getItemById("1265352723")
      preguntaFecha.asListItem().setChoiceValues(opcionesFecha)
    }**
    
        function ultimaFila(col,hoja) {
          const libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
          const ultimaFila = hoja.getMaxRows();
          const rango=hoja.getRange(1,col,hoja.getMaxRows()).getValues();
          for (i = ultimaFila-1; i > 0; i--){
            if (rango[i][0]){
              return i+1;
            }
          }
        }
```

Entonces el error aparece justamente en esta área y no se como solucionarlo, cabe decir que el código que he hecho es para actualizar los horarios disponibles que los tengo establecidos en sheets.

```
//Actualizar Fecha
      **const preguntaFecha = formulario.getItemById("1265352723")
      preguntaFecha.asListItem().setChoiceValues(opcionesFecha)
    }**
```